# Regex: Conditional removal after slash

Tags: python, regex

I've been attempting to get rid of strings after forward slash with certain rules.

When findings a forward slash remove the strings, check if there are more than one word before the slash and more than one word after slash (if two phrases are separated by slash) to remove the strings after the slash:

```
REYNOLDS COMMUNITY CENTER/CENTRALE DE SOINS REYNOLDS
```

The previous example has three words before the slash and four words after slash, then the final result should be:

```
REYNOLDS COMMUNITY CENTER
```

However, in the following example:

```
AB/CDE COMMUNITY CENTER
```

The string after / remains because there are more than one word (there are three words) and before the slash there is just one word. In this case, just the slash is removed to get a final result as the following:

```
AB CDE COMMUNITY CENTER
```

If we have the following string:

```
REYNOLDS COMMUNITY CENTER/24
```

The final string should be:

```
REYNOLDS COMMUNITY CENTER 24
```

First check there are more than one word before slash (it contains three) and there is just one word after slash (24). Then, the slash is removed.

The rule is to keep just the string before the slash as long as there are more than one word in each side of the /. On the other hand, if there is just one word in any side of the /, then the slash should be removed.

I've attempted to get the previous behavior without success so far with the following snippet:

```
import re
lst= ['REYNOLDS COMMUNITY CENTER/CENTRALE DE SOINS REYNOLDS',
      '100/10 COMMUNITY CENTER',
      'ROGERS COMMUNITY CENTER/CENTRAL CARE',
      'AB/CDE COMMUNITY CENTER',
      'REYNOLDS COMMUNITY CENTER/24']


for element in lst:
    result = re.sub(r'(^\w+\s+\w+[^/]+)/([A-Za-z]+(?:[^A-Za-z\n]+[A-Za-z]+)+[^A-Za-z\n]*$)?',
                    '\1',
                    element,
                    0,
                    re.IGNORECASE)
    print(result)
```

The previous examples should give the following results:

```
REYNOLDS COMMUNITY CENTER
100 10 COMMUNITY CENTER
ROGERS COMMUNITY CENTER
AB CDE COMMUNITY CENTER
REYNOLDS COMMUNITY CENTER 24
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I've updated the regex in my answer so the final '24' is returned.  (?i)^(.*? .*?)\/[^\d]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is bulletproof for a bigger list, but for the list supplied, try the following:

```
import re

lst= ['REYNOLDS COMMUNITY CENTER/CENTRALE DE SOINS REYNOLDS',
      '100/10 COMMUNITY CENTER',
      'ROGERS COMMUNITY CENTER/CENTRAL CARE',
      'AB/CDE COMMUNITY CENTER']

pattern_slash_with_word_before_it = re.compile(r'(?i)^(.*? .*?)\/[^\d]')

for element in lst:
    if pattern_slash_with_word_before_it.search(element):
        print(pattern_slash_with_word_before_it.search(element)[1])
    else:
        print(element.replace('/', ' '))
```

Outputs:

```
REYNOLDS COMMUNITY CENTER
100 10 COMMUNITY CENTER
ROGERS COMMUNITY CENTER
AB CDE COMMUNITY CENTER 24
```

This solution really only considers it is a string with a slash but words before it, or it is not so replace slashes with spaces.  Maybe it's food for thought.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's a complete solution to the problem or not, this is certainly a cool reduction of it as presented at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex

```
r" (?:\w+\s)+\w+(\/.*)|\w+(\/).*
```

replacing the content of capture group 1 (if matched) with an empty string and the contents of capture group 2 (if matched) with a space.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QZx59F/3/)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations:

```
(?:\w+\s+)+  # match 1+ word chars followed by 1+ spaces
\w+          # match 1+ word chars
(\/.*)       # match '/' followed by 1+ chars in capture group 1
|            # or
\w+          # match 1+ word chars
(\/)         # match '/' in capture group 2
.*           # match 1+ chars
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not do this with RE. Recursion and conditionals notwithstanding, you can't *count* per se with an expression. Why not solve this with string functions? Split, count words and join where necessary. For example:

```py
out = []
lst = ['REYNOLDS COMMUNITY CENTER/CENTRALE DE SOINS REYNOLDS',
      '100/10 COMMUNITY CENTER',
      'ROGERS COMMUNITY CENTER/CENTRAL CARE',
      'AB/CDE COMMUNITY CENTER',
      'REYNOLDS COMMUNITY CENTER/24']

for item in lst:
    parts = item.split("/")
    # leave item as is if there was no split:
    if len(parts) == 1:
        out.append(item)
        continue
    # Get number of words for halves:
    wordsL = len(parts[0].split())
    wordsR = len(parts[1].split())
    # Rules:
    if wordsL > 1 and wordsR > 1:
        out.append(parts[0])
    elif wordsL == 1 and wordsR > 1:
        out.append(" ".join(parts))
    elif wordsL > 1 and wordsR == 1:
        out.append(" ".join(parts))

print(out)
```

I don't use Python much, as you can probably tell. ^^; Output:

```
['REYNOLDS COMMUNITY CENTER', 
'100 10 COMMUNITY CENTER', 
'ROGERS COMMUNITY CENTER', 
'AB CDE COMMUNITY CENTER', 
'REYNOLDS COMMUNITY CENTER 24']
```